# Register which anchor tag made a postback?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

There a two different navigation menues on a page in their own seperate usercontrols. The menu items in the two menus can navigate to the same pages.
The topmenu has some jQuery animation and the leftmenu has not.

The question is how can I get which anchor tag in a navigation menu made a postback when the anchor tag is in a repeater and the repeater is in a usercontrol(The anchor tags are dynamically created). The problem is that the topmenu usercontrol codebehind runs and sets some values for hiddenfields so the jQuery animation will run properly for the topmenu, but when the leftmenu is clicked it should not run and set the hiddenfields in the topmenu codebehind. So I need to figure out how to differentiate between the two menus.

Here is the repeater markup:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RightSide">
        <HeaderTemplate><ul></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li data-type="<%# ((Item)Container.DataItem).HasChildren ? "dropdown" : "link" %>" class="<%# ((Item)Container.DataItem).HasChildren ? "dropdown" : "link" %>">
                <a href='<%# GetLink(((Item)Container.DataItem),"MenuLink") %>'><%#((Item)Container.DataItem)["MenuTitle"] %></a>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

TopMenu .cs code:

```
public partial class TopMenu
{
    private ID _homeId = new ID("{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RightSide.DataSource = GetMultiList("Right side", RootItem);
        RightSide.DataBind();

        ***HERE I NEED TO MAKE THE CHECK.
        So the code below should only run if the postback came from the topmenu***

        var sectionItem = GetAncestorOrDefault(CurrentItem);

        Sitecore.Data.Database context = Sitecore.Context.Database;
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item homeItem = context.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");

        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multilistField = homeItem.Fields["Right Side"];

        foreach (string id in multilistField)
        {
            Sitecore.Data.Items.Item multiItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items.GetItem(id);

            if (multiItem.HasChildren)
            {
                items.Add(multiItem);
            }
        }

        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
            if (item.Name.Equals(sectionItem.Name))
            {
                hiddenAttr.Value = sectionItem.Name;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                hiddenAttr.Value = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with eventtarget but it is always null and also with hidden field which value is always "" in the codebehind. I am out of ideas...

I will post more code if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Örvar

Comment: did you try __doPostback ??

Comment: @Ankit It does not work. I get a uncaught typeerror: cannot read property'__eventtarget of undefined. I suspect it is because my anchor tag is in the repeater. I am not sure where I should put my __doPostBack function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting all values in postback. Wrap the code in if(!IsPostBack){} for repeater data binding:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        RightSide.DataSource = GetMultiList("Right side", RootItem);
        RightSide.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {   
     // ***HERE I NEED TO MAKE THE CHECK.
        // So the code below should only run if the postback came from the topmenu***

        var sectionItem = GetAncestorOrDefault(CurrentItem);

        Sitecore.Data.Database context = Sitecore.Context.Database;
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item homeItem = context.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");

        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multilistField = homeItem.Fields["Right Side"];

        foreach (string id in multilistField)
        {
            Sitecore.Data.Items.Item multiItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items.GetItem(id);

            if (multiItem.HasChildren)
            {
                items.Add(multiItem);
            }
        }

        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
            if (item.Name.Equals(sectionItem.Name))
            {
                hiddenAttr.Value = sectionItem.Name;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                hiddenAttr.Value = String.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I would suggest using a query parameter in  tag. If the href is 
`"/MyContent/MyPgae1"` 
you can change it to 
`"/MyContent/MyPgae1?s=r"` 
and in the postback :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            RightSide.DataSource = GetMultiList("Right side", RootItem);
            RightSide.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {   
            if(Request.QueryString["s"] == "r")
            {
                //request is from rightmenu
            }
```

Comment: Thanks alot! this has actually solved my problem. I am very greatfull for your help!